# ANSI C: Displaying frames of animation in terminal at constant FPS

Tags: c, terminal, ascii, conways-game-of-life

I'm struggling to grasp how I should tackle the problem of how to do simple ASCII animation in terminal in C.

As my class assignment I need make simple Conway's game of life in C. Game "board" will be stored in one dimensional array. Number of rows and columns is taken from user input. I have no problem displaying it in terminal with scrolling , but I would like it be proper animation, without terminal scrolling and displaying garbage (not actual code in project, just trying to explain)

```
void draw(int *board, rows, columns){
     for(int j =0; j < rows; j++){
          for(int i = 0; i < columns;i++){
               printf((*board+i));
          } printf("/n");
     }

/*****************************************************************      
Here I would like to have code that clears terminal screen , returns 
carriage to the begging so on the next call of function 
draw(int*board...) terminal windows is clear and next frame will be 
drawn without being garbage, as if it would be the first printf 
being called in this program, after waiting 33 miliseconds  ( sleep() ?)
******************************************************************/


runGame(); /* actual game code does game of life stuff in the array*/
}
```

After many tries I failed to find anything useful or anything that would actually work. I would prefer not to use ncurses, as this project needs to be as lean and core as possible.

I DO NOT DEMAND THAT YOU WRITE CODE FOR ME ! (would be too good :P )
I just want to hear your ideas and what function should I use to clear terminal window etc.

MANY,MANY thanks :)

Comment: "I would prefer not to use ncurses" - well, this is your only sensible option. If you write your own terminal routines, it's not going to be any more "lean and core". A terminal library is the right tool for the job.

Comment: I see. So no clever hacks to do this in the terminal window, purely as a text ? Anything would be good.

Comment: All the clever terminal hacks fail to illustrate one important point.  There's more than one terminal, and the characters they "wake up and pay attention to" are slightly different, as are the features they provide.  So, a library that attempts to make them all fall under one api (curses) is the sensible way to go.

Answer (score 3):

Found a clever hack ! :D Kinda stupid to answer my own question but someone might benefit from it.

```
printf("%c[2J%c[;H",(char) 27, (char) 27);
```

This line clears anything in front and back of the cursor and puts it back on [0,0] position !

ASCII has some fancy escape codes which can do miracles really. I wil update this answer when I find reliable way to control refresh rate. http://www.termsys.demon.co.uk/vtansi.htm

EDIT: usleep(33000) does the job. Usleep() takes microseconds, multiply by 1000 to get miliseconds.

Comment: Not stupid at all ! You're contributing to the knowledge base, and that's what SO is all about. You can accept your own answer, too :)

Comment: Glad you posted your answer, but to be clear, those are VT100 terminal codes, not ASCII terminal codes.  If someone uses a non-VT100 terminal, it might work, if the terminal they use is VT100 compatible.  Some are, some are "almost"; but, VT100 is getting old-in-the-tooth.  Newer terminals (gnome-terminal) support more colors, and other features.  In the end it's always a trade-off, so don't feel bad if there isn't a 100% correct solution.